# Ember JS: render a list of items programmatically

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How do we generate a list of people in the below example programmatically in Ember JS?

```
{{#each App.peopleController}}
  {{#view App.PersonView contentBinding="this"}}
    {{content.firstName}} {{content.lastName}}
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

I've tried using

```
App.peopleController.forEach(function(person) {
  App.PersonView.create({contentBinding: person}).render();
})
```

but I got the error 'data.buffer' is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try v.appendTo("#container") instead.